# Difference between phrases "be the same something" and "have the same something"

Tags: difference

Why have the speaker used "be" instead of "have" in the following sentence? "Stars are not the same brightness." I am confused because it seems to me that the word "brightness" has been used there as an adjective. What if the speaker had used "have", for example, " Stars don't have the same brightness", would it mean the same? If not, what is the difference then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. The given sentence is not good English.

**Stars are not equally bright** or **Stars do not have equal brightness** are both grammatical ways to express the intended thought (though both offend my sense of good English style).

It is possible that the sentence quoted contains a typographical error and should have read:

**Stars are not of the same brightness**

The addition of "of" makes the sentence grammatical although again it seems poor style to me.

How would I have expressed the thought?

**Not all stars are equally bright" or **Stars vary in brightness**.